# How to add ILogger to send email service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, blazor, asp.net-core-logging

I have a Blazor project and use MailKit for sending emails.

I'd like to add Logger to the email service.

That is `Startup.ConfigureServices`

```
//...
services.AddSingleton<IEmailConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration").Get<EmailConfiguration>());
//...
services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
//...
```

That is the `EmailSender` service:

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    private readonly IEmailConfiguration _emailConfiguration;
    //private readonly ILogger<WHATModel> _logger; //<------------?

    public EmailSender(IEmailConfiguration emailConfiguration)
    {
        _emailConfiguration = emailConfiguration;
    }

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string recipientEmail, string subject, string message)
    {

//....
```

So, I can pass `EmailConfiguration` to the service but how I can pass a `ILogger`?

It requires some model

```
private readonly ILogger<WHATModel> _logger; //<------------?
```

What model should I pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model is usually the type being injected into and acts as the category for identifying and grouping the logged information. `ILogger<TCategoryName>`

> When an `ILogger` object is created, a category is specified for it. That category is included with each log message created by that instance of `ILogger`. The category may be any string, but the convention is to use the class name, such as "TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController".

Reference [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core: Log category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#log-category)

Include it in the constructor as an explicit dependency so that it can also be injected

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender {
    private readonly IEmailConfiguration emailConfiguration;
    private readonly ILogger<EmailSender> logger;

    public EmailSender(IEmailConfiguration emailConfiguration, ILogger<EmailSender> logger) {
        this.emailConfiguration = emailConfiguration;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string recipientEmail, string subject, string message) {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

The container will resolve and inject the dependency into the sender when resolving it.